# Excel VBA - File not found on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I have a function to open a file picker dialog on Mac (Excel 2015) and return the path. The code is below but I think the path is the problem, not the code and I don't have a Mac to debug it myself. The path returned by the function is:

> SSD:Users:UserName:Downloads:timesheet-export (40).csv

I've amended :UserName: but it does correctly the show user. The file does exist in this location, I asked the user to send me the path and they sent:

> /Users/UserName/Downloads/timesheet-export (40).csv

```
Function GetFileMac()

Dim myPath As String
Dim myScript As String
Dim myFiles As String
Dim mySplit As Variant
Dim n As Long
Dim fName As String
Dim myBook As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
myPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")

myScript = _
"set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
           "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
         " {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text""} " & _
           "with prompt ""Please select the time sheet file"" default location alias """ & _
           myPath & """ multiple selections allowed false) as string" & vbNewLine & _
           "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
           "return theFiles"

myFiles = MacScript(myScript)
On Error GoTo 0

If myFiles <> "" Then

    mySplit = Split(myFiles, ",")
    GetFileMac = mySplit(0)

End If

End Function
```

When I run this, I get error 1004 file no found, but as mentioned above a path is picked up and is available in the fp string:

```
Dim fp as string

' if user on Mac etc... then

fp = GetFileMac

Set someWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fp) ' error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the path format.

To make a mac path like this

```
SSD:Users:UserName:Downloads:timesheet-export (40).csv
```

To a POSIX path like this

```
/Users/UserName/Downloads/timesheet-export (40).csv
```

Use:

```
set myPath to POSIX path of myPath
```